# Text Suggestions scrolling with page: Issue with devbridge.com "Autocomplete Text Box"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using devbridge.com "Autocomplete Text Box"; required .js file can be downloaded from:
https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

In my webpage layout, I have kept fixed header, fixed left navigation and control area, fixed right content area, and scroll-able middle area. I have added Text Input in fixed left navigation and control area. As I am using external resource (appropriate jquery.autocomplete.min.js by devbridge.com needs to be downloaded), my entire problem can't be replicated in jsfiddle.net, but I have still posted the code skeleton over there.

https://jsfiddle.net/odwkfpqp/

The exact problem is: once the web page is loaded, as soon as user type text in text-box, suggestions pops up; in this example typing "va" will do the magic. With suggestions pop-up intact (i.e. no select action yet), if user scrolls the web page up or down, the suggestions pop-up element moves too. That element is not fixed with respect to text input control. How can I do that? I have tried lot of options in CSS but all in vain.

**HTML Code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <title>Input Text AutoComplete</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prc.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="prc.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div id="left" class="left">
                    <input type="text" class="autosearch" id="autosearch" name="autosearch" placeholder="Search"/>
                </div>
                <div id="middle" class="middle">
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p align="right">hello</p>
                </div>
                <div id="right" class="right">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Java Script Code**

```
$(function(){
    var nvarr = [
        { name: "name0", value: "value0" },
        { name: "name1", value: "value1" },
        { name: "name2", value: "value2" },
        { name: "name3", value: "value3" },
        { name: "name4", value: "value4" },
        { name: "name5", value: "value5" },
        { name: "name6", value: "value6" },
        { name: "name7", value: "value7" },
        { name: "name8", value: "value8" },
        { name: "name9", value: "value9" },
    ];

    $('#autosearch').autocomplete({
        lookup: nvarr,
        onSelect: function (nv) {
            alert(nv.name + " " + nv.vlaue);
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS Code**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

div.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

div.header {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #6B7A8F;
}

div.content {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

div.left,div.right {
    width: 150px;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #77C9D4;
}

div.middle {
    margin: 50px 150px 0px;
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    min-height: 100%;
}

div.content,div.left,div.right {
    height: 100%;
}

div.left {
    left: 0;
}

div.right {
    right: 0;
}

input.autosearch {
    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

input.autosearch {
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    height: 30px;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 4px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 4px);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;  
}

.autocomplete-suggestions { background: #fff; cursor: default; overflow: auto;}
.autocomplete-suggestion { padding: 10px 5px; font-family: serif; font-size: 12px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: scroll; }
.autocomplete-selected { background: #f0f0f0; }
.autocomplete-suggestions strong { font-weight: normal; color: #3399ff; }
```

Comment: your fiddle is not working! nothing pops up! because jQuery is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these two properties to your CSS to override the *top* and *position* properties:

```
.autocomplete-suggestions { 
  position: fixed !important;
  background: #fff; 
  cursor: default;  
  overflow: auto; 
  top: 82px !important;
}
```

Comment: Marouen, I have already tried that and it is still not working. Provided fiddle is not working because it needs external resource for which there is no CDN link and I don't know how to download and add external .js in fiddle to make it work.

Comment: @NimishJain: this works fine for me. Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/j766q6no/

Comment: It was my mistake. I was not overriding the suggested properties using the !important modifier. It is now working like a charm for me as well. Thank you.